# Simple way to get a .net DLL to run as a Windows Service

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, windows-services

I have an NServiceBus project (Class Library) that I would like to have run in a Windows Service (right now it uses the NServiceBus.Host.exe)

I would like to be able to put as little around my dll as possible.  What is the simplest way to get a dll to run as a Windows Service?

I would rather not make an separate installer, but if I have to make an installer, I will.

Comment: Running a DLL as a service and installing the library (GAC or not) are 2 unrelated subjects.

Comment: @joe, thanks.  I updated my question.  (I had a co-worker tell me that it could be done "easily" if you put your dll in the GAC.  Something I don't want to do.)

Comment: @Vaccano Tell your co-worker to take some classes on .net programming and/or windows services, the two have absolutely no correlation. =)

Comment: How much of the Start/Stop/Pause and Threading logic is provided by this DLL?

Comment: @HenkHolterman - My dll runs on a single thread.  It just runs until killed.  (No Stop/Start or pause.)

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use the NSB host? ( nservicebus.host.exe /install will install it as a win service)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, NServiceBus host uses TopShelf underneath. Anyways, this should be what you are looking for: http://nservicebus.com/GenericHost.aspx > Installation

Answer (score 3):

There is no simpler way than writing a windows service that wraps your library.  You will need something that does the work of communicating with the Service Control Manager (responding to start, stops, etc) and also handles the "main loop" for the service.  The only way to do that, other than something someone else has written (like NServiceBus.Host.exe) is to write one yourself.

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Service Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y817hyb6.aspx)

And just call the class library from the service...

Answer (score 1):

While I haven't used it myself, some peers have enjoyed using [TopShelf](http://topshelf-project.com) - apparently the nicest feature (well, the one they liked) is being able to update the service with an xcopy instead of having to stop/remove/install/start every time.